# How to access the different panels in QGIS Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I accidentally closed the tabs in composer: Composition and Properties, I think it is called.

The question: How can I open them again?

Answer (score 1):

- Method 1:

  - In `Print composer`, click on `View -> Panel` and the panels should be there
- Method 2:

  - In `Print composer`, right click on the toolbar and enable the panels that are disabled

Comment: @NiklasGroop The best way to say "thanks" here is to upvote and/or accept the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)